# Are there the equivalent of chimpanzees, etc. on other worlds with humanoids?

Tags: star-trek, biology

I mean, on Vulcan or Chronos are there "primates" that resemble the humanoids that correspond to humans on Earth?

EDIT: Reading about Klingon evolution it seems very possible that during the evolution from crustacean to modern Klingon that some other primate-like forms would have arisen. If we don't have much canonical info on primate-like Klingons or Vulcans it is because, I suspect, there is not much reason to present such creatures. I suspect that if we saw a Vulcan medical research lab (if they do not exclude animals from experiments for moral reasons) in an episode or movie, we would see them working with not terrestrial rats or monkeys but some Vulcan equivalent -- but this would just be a quick scene unless of course someone writes a Planet of the Apes-like movie but set on Vulcan with instead of the Liberty being buried in the sand it would be Surak and Spock or whoever would show a little self-control for crying out loud at the end.

Comment: Klingons did NOT evolve from crustaceans any more than Barkley evolved from a spider.   This is a serious misunderstanding of the episode and I beg you to edit out the edit that says that lest that nonsense continues to spread.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: please give me a link that explains why this is wrong.

Comment: Barclay transformed into a spider.  Would you say humans evolved from spiders the same way you did crustacean and klingon? I assure you in natural history spiders and humans split from something that looked like neither about 525million years ago and after that the only thing in common was having a left and right side symmetry.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbilaterian  last common ancestor and Barclay spider https://youtu.be/g1YoHcKnOGE  sorry the episode certainly leads one to think that about klingons and I thought that as a kid but now it is a pet peeve.

Comment: @releseabe I have always wondered this, but I would assume, with information from The Chase, that there are primates on other worlds.

Comment: In the TOS,episode "A Private Little War" we Kirk is attacked by an indigenous creature called a Mugato described as a "horned white-furred gorilla-like creature".

Comment: @releseabe - Data himself says in the episode why the various humans are transforming into different things: "Because introns can include genetic material from many different species over millions of years of evolution, it is possible that a wide variety of transformations is occurring among the crew." - here's your link :) - http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/271.htm

Comment: "a Planet of the Apes-like movie but set on Vulcan" — SPOCK: It would appear that our forebears, whether purely inadvertently or through negligence bordering on malice, 'blew it all to hell'. SURAK: Such illogical creatures. _[FADE TO BLACK]_

Answer (score 2):

Non-sentient, ape or monkey-like creatures have certainly been shown to exist on alien worlds in the Star Trek universe. This clip (from the Voyager episode "[Resolutions](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Resolutions_(episode))")  of Janeway encountering a small animal resembling a vervet monkey on a planet in the Delta Quadrant is a good example.

I gather from the way your question is phrased though, that you're specifically interested in evidence that at least some humanoid aliens in Star Trek *evolved* from simpler primate species, much as humans are believed to have done on Earth. If so, that's a bit trickier. I don't believe there's explicit evidence of primates existing, or having existed, on the homeworlds of the Klingons, Vulcans, Romulans, Ferengi, etc, aside from the aforementioned species themselves.

It's worth noting that there are indications that the Vulcan race may not have originated on the planet Vulcan, in which case we shouldn't expect to see any of their evolutionary ancestors there. For example, in the TOS episode, "[Return to Tomorrow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Return_to_Tomorrow_(episode))", Spock suggested that Vulcans could be the descendants of alien colonists.

> SARGON: A body much as yours, my children, although our minds were infinitely greater.
>
> KIRK: That's twice you've referred to us as my children.
>
> SARGON: Because it is possible you are our descendants, Captain Kirk. Six thousand centuries ago, our vessels were colonising this galaxy, just as your own starships have now begun to explore that vastness. As you now leave your own seed on distant planets, so we left our seed behind us. Perhaps your own legends of an Adam and an Eve were two of our travellers.
>
> MULHALL: Our beliefs and our studies indicate that life on our planet, Earth, evolved independently.
>
> SPOCK: That would tend, however, to explain certain elements of Vulcan prehistory.
>
> <sub>[Star Trek: TOS "Return to Tomorrow" script](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/51.htm)</sub>

And in the TNG episode, "[Who Watches the Watchers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Who_Watches_The_Watchers_(episode))", the Mintakans -- a community of somewhat primitive proto-Vulcans -- were shown to be living on the planet, Mintaka III, completely unaware that Vulcans existed elsewhere.

[Robert Fletcher](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_Fletcher) -- a costume designer who helped redesign Klingons for *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* -- thought that Klingons evolved like crustaceans, with their cranial ridges being vestiges of what were once full-blown exoskeletons.

> FLETCHER: In my mind, all the bumps on the forehead and so forth are vestigial remains of a people that evolved like crustaceans, like lobsters, who have their skeleton on the outside of their bodies, and over the millions of years, they've lost that complete outside skeleton, but now retain only vestiges of it.
>
> <sub>[https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Depicting_Klingons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Depicting_Klingons#Film_redesign)</sub>

That isn't strictly canon, just his opinion, but it is arguably supported by the TNG episode, "[Genesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Genesis_(episode))", where Worf was devolved or mutated into a somewhat monstrous, bipedal creature with exoskeletal armour, which could've been a progenitor of modern Klingons.

Comment: Thanks. I recall the horned gorilla from STOS but the seeding of planets or guiding evolution thing is too much for me -- i dont even have a phd. You are right, I am interested if there are genetically-related primates, not necessarily from which Vulcans evolved but I guess that is implied. I have long been troubled with the idea that Klingon evolved from crabs -- wow, what nonsense. But again, no phd...

Comment: Not sure if you're aware or not, but the Voyager episode, "[Distant Origin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Distant_Origin_(episode))", revealed that a humanoid race residing in the Delta Quadrant had originally evolved from reptiles on Earth.

Comment: Not explicitly aware but my understanding is that some race distantly in the past guided the evolution of various species throughout the galaxy (universe?) to create humanoid species and the starting species did not have to be mammalian or even vertebrates. Have you ever tried to guide the evolution of an invertebrate species so that it eventually becomes a vertebrate, let alone mammal (which I assume both Klingon and Vulcan are)?

Comment: The TNG episode, "[The Chase](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Chase_(episode))", established that a race of ancient humanoids seeded various worlds in the Milky Way (including Earth, Vulcan, Kronos and Cardassia Prime) with their DNA, hoping to create a lasting legacy of their existence. They didn't go into much detail about guiding the evolution of various species beyond that initial seeding though. Perhaps they just wanted to ensure that their DNA would be present in whatever lifeforms evolved, and hoped for the best in terms of what natural selection would go on to deliver.

Comment: That same TNG episode had Barkley turn into a spider mutant which has no direct relation to anything on the chordate/ mammal / human evolution tree.  The claim that klingons are evolved crustaceans is a serious misunderstanding of the episode and was something that thankfully was edited out of the Wikipedia a long time ago.  Hopefully it hasn't returned.  Please edit your answer so that nonsense doesn't spread.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - There's no clear indication that Klingons evolved _from_ crustaceans, but [according to Robert Fletcher](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Depicting_Klingons) -- who helped redesign Klingons for _Star Trek: The Motion Picture_ -- they did evolve _like_ crustaceans, with the cranial ridges being vestiges of what were once full-blown exoskeletons. It's therefore possible that the creature Worf mutated into in "Genesis" was a direct ancestor of modern Klingons. I will however edit my answer to say that it _may have been_ a progenitor, rather than _was_.

Comment: Just going to pull you up on _as humans are believed to have done on Earth_, should be _as humans are **proven** to have done on Earth_. It's a fact, it's not a matter of opinion or belief, there is - literally - overwhelming evidence that humans and primates share a common ancestor.

Comment: @Binary Worrier - Saying that something is believed to be true doesn't necessarily mean it isn't a well-founded belief; it could mean that, but it doesn't have to, nor was it intended to in this specific instance. That said, there's little if anything we can know with absolute certainty, given how limited and fallible human perceptions and memories are. A true science fiction fan should understand that more than most; have you never watched _The Matrix_, or _Total Recall_? :)

Comment: @LogicDictates: I remember distinctly watching The Matrix but did I really??

Answer (score 2):

The Enterprise episode [Dear Doctor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dear_Doctor_(episode)) has the Enterprise encounter a pre-warp planet who's population consists of two different humanoid species, the Valakians and the Menk.

Both are sentient, though the Menk are considered inferior, and as the planet is pre-warp it is probably reasonable to assume that they both come from the same evolutionary setting rather than one being imported by the other.

From the dialogue in the episode, this is not uncommon in the Star Trek universe.

> ...from Phlox's perspective, the Valakians and Menk have found a way to live in harmony, when on most planets with more than one sentient race, they fight each other until only one survives.